# Question about the cardinality of compact sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am curious how to distinguished between the cardinality of a compact set [a,b] and the cardinality of the open set (a,b).

If I know that my set [a,b] is a compact set can I say that there are uncoutably many but finite elements in that set? Or is it true that there are infinitely many elements in that set. (assuming we are discussing reals and not, for example, integers).

And if they are the same, then how?

I am curious about examples like the following:

$\forall x \in [a,b] \exists y \in [a,b] s.t. x>y$ and if there are an uncountablely finite amount of elements in $[a,b]$ then there exist three elements such that we violate transitivity by the pigeon hole principle...yes?

If there are infinitely many elements then maybe this is not the case?

Can anyone give a bit of clarity?

Comment: An uncountable set is necessarily infinite.

Comment: They are the same cardinality. There is a (very discontinuous) bijection between them.

Answer (score 1):

The cardinalities of $[a,b]$ and $(a, b)$ are the same: Take a sequenceof distinct elements $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ in $[a,b]$ with $p_0 = a$ and set $f(p_n) = p_{n+1}$. This $f$ is bijective and extends to a bijection between $[a, b]$ and $(a,b]$ by setting $f(p) = p$ if $p$ is not one of the $p_n$. Do a similar construction to get rid of $b$. This gives you a bijection between $[a,b]$ and $(a,b)$. In a more general sense, you can always remove finitely many elements from an infinite set without changing cardinality using this argument.

Both intervals are of uncountable cardinality as you can see by "stretching" the interval $(-1, 1)$ to the real line, use e.g. $x \mapsto \tan((\pi/2) x)$. Thus there is a bijection between the real numbers and any interval, and the real numbers are uncountable. To my understanding, saying that a set is uncountable and finite makes no sense.

Comment: Perhaps it is finite but so large that you can never finish counting it? =P

Comment: Def. Uncountably finite set: a finite set which large enough that a mathematician will never finish counting it, i.e. any set with more than two elements. :P

Comment: More seriously, here is an explicit example of an uncountable finite set: $\{1,0.101010101010\dots\}$. The reason you cannot count how many members it has is that you can never tell whether there is a comma coming. Okay even more seriously, I don't know why I forgot to make your answer's vote count change to its successor.